# Visual Editor cannot search for images in MediaWiki local uploads

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

I've installed the latest MediaWiki and the latest Visual Editor, everything is looking great but I have one problem though. All my uploaded images cannot be searched when adding media to the article. Can anybody please enlighten me.

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Is your wiki private?

Comment: I am using the latest verion of wiki, and no my wiki is not private. Although you still need to login to edit. but anyone can read it.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about the versions. :) What exact MediaWiki and Visual Editor versions do you have on `Special:Version`? “Latest” can mean a lot of things...

Comment: Also: Does it work if you search for an image with *the full, exact image name, including the extension*? E.g. `My image.jpg`.

Comment: 1.22.6 - mediawiki
0.1.0 - VisualEditor

Comment: Also, I've tried searching using the media on the VisualEditor but it failed to search the image.
But searching the file using the search bar on the mediawiki "File:Test.jpg" showed some result.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. You can always try the latest development versions of MW (1.23) & VE, as VE is under heavy development (and not yet recommended for production deployment outside the Wikimedia wikis, btw). And add a link to your wiki, if you want me to have a closer look.

Comment: BTW, may I ask if you've tried the mediasearch of the VisualEditor? If yes how did you make it work and what is your version?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I know many ppl have had problems. Sometimes related to restricted user permissions, and sometimes related to the MW search backend

Comment: Okay. I am not alone. :) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The search bar autocompletion uses the prefix search, which is not what VE uses. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

Things are in flux (some tweaks were needed after CirrusSearch), but VisualEditor's [MWMediaSearchWidget](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EVED/browse/master/modules/ve-mw/ui/widgets/ve.ui.MWMediaSearchWidget.js) uses the [srsearch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search).

In MediaWiki defaults, this will be a simplistic full text MySQL search, which doesn't do stemming or anything hence is very likely to miss results compared to CirrusSearch.

Additionally, and perhaps more importantly (depending on your wiki), it won't include media from remote repositories like Wikimedia Commons. I'm not sure what to do in that case, perhaps the widget should be modified to (also) query the remote repository's API.

Comment: This question is one year old (I'm not using mediawiki anymore) and I think much has improved since then, I think as - far as I rememberd, the [band-aid] solution I made was to update my mediawiki (or was it ve) to the development version. So yeah, thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @mateeyow, remember to self-answer you next time then! Your question was interesting. :) And it still is, so my answer (hopefully correct as of now).